# Record count in report per page in access

Tags: ms-access

> ```
> ***
> ```
>
> I have a report that has detail ,I want to display count of the
>   records per page in the report footer
>
> ---

Comment: See if this does what you want https://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=3069

Comment: Thanks for your link It's working well

Answer (score 0):

Steps as outlined in https://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=3069

1) Place a textbox in the {page} footer, and call it txtPageCount.  Be sure to set the Format property to standard, or some other numeric type.  Modify the label, e.g., "Page Counts: ".

2) Click on the Report Properties button (which is located to the left of the horizontal ruler, and just below the toolbars).  Click on the Event tab, then click on "On Open".  Click the 3 dots at the end of the line, then select Code Builder.

3) Go up to the listbox that contains the word "Report", and click on the arrow.  Select "(General)".  The right listbox should now show "Declarations".  Enter this code:
   `Public intPageCount As Integer`
   '"Public" variables stay alive until the report finishes

4) Scroll back down to "Private Sub Report_Open..." and paste this code into the procedure:

```
   ' the following code initializes the variable 
    intPageCount = 0
```

5) Go back to listbox that contains the word "Report", and select "Detail", then select "Print" in the righthand listbox.  Enter the following code:

```
   ' increment intPageCount for each record printed
    intPageCount = intPageCount + 1
```

6) Go back to the listbox and select "PageFooterSection", and select "Format" in the righthand listbox.  Insert this code:

```
    'set the textbox in the footer to intPageCount
    txtPageCount = intPageCount
    'reset our counter (intPageCount)
    intPageCount = 0
```